# URL Rewriting in Asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to Asp.net MVC. 
I am creating web application, where i have to rewrite url with product name. 
I am not sure if that is possible or not in MVC.

Like, 
http://sitename.com/category1/product1

http://sitename.com/category1/product2

will have same page.

Comment: Is not clear your question. What do you want exactly ?

Comment: That is why you choosen MVC. it is built in. SEO friendly url. Even now webform supports.

Comment: by default your product part of the url is the `Action` part inside your controller, if that is what you want, it can be done !

Answer (score 0):

There are facilities to generate friendly urls within MVC.

Check out the article at - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs - for an overview of how this is handled in MVC.

Essentially, you need to configure the routes on application startup as follows.  This can usually be done in the `global.asax` file but cna be split for areas etc.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

   routes.MapRoute(
      "Default",                                              // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
   );
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); // Reigster the routes
}
```

This is the default route but you can define as required.